# How to convert PyTorch Tensor to Numpy ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, computer-vision, pytorch

I have this function that rotates the MNIST images. The function returns a pytorch Tensor. I am more familiar with Tensorflow and I want to convert the pytorch tensor to a numpy ndarray that I can use. Is there a function that will allow me to do that? I tried to modify the function a little bit by adding .numpy() after `tensor(img.rotate(rotation)).view(784)` and save it in an empty ndarray, but that didn't work. Parameter `d` is MNIST data saved in `.pt` (pytensor, I think). Thanks! (Would love to know if there is a tensorflow function that can rotate the data.)

```
t = 1
min_rot = 1.0 * t / 20 * (180 - 0) + \
        0
max_rot = 1.0 * (t + 1) / 20 * \
    (180 - 0) + 0
rot = random.random() * (max_rot - min_rot) + min_rot
rotate_dataset(x_tr, rot)
```

```
def rotate_dataset(d, rotation):
    result = torch.FloatTensor(d.size(0), 784)
    tensor = transforms.ToTensor()

    for i in range(d.size(0)):
        img = Image.fromarray(d[i].numpy(), mode='L')
        result[i] = tensor(img.rotate(rotation)).view(784)
    return result
```

Comment: What didn't work?  According the `torch` docs, a `Tensor` object has a `.numpy` method.  What do you mean by `save it to an empty ndarray`?  I won't ask for runable code (since I don't have `torch`), but you should show enough code and results (even errors) so we have a clear idea of what you have attempted.

Answer (score 0):

How about not converting to `tensor` in the first place:

```py
result[i] = np.array(img.rotate(rotation)).flatten()
```

Comment: Got ```AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'flatten'```

Comment: @AmartyaBarua you might also want to convert the numpy array to float32